# Using websocket node to stream commands to python shell

Tags: node.js, stream, websocket, socket.io, node.js-stream

I trying to build a web app with terminal command line access to a python shell, but I'm having some difficulty with streams.

I have a node.js/websocket server that sends incoming commands to the stdin of a python process (code below), which seems to work alright, BUT for some reason multiple response messages are being sent for each incoming command. For example, if the command `'hello world'` is sent, multiple `'hello world'`s are sent back to the client (along with multiple `>>>` through stderr). I'm pretty stumped... I've ensured that only a single command is coming from the client, so why am I getting some many responses?

```
var python = spawn('python', ['-i']);
s.on('run', function(input) {
  console.log('Running command: ' + input.command);
  python.stdin.write(input.command + '\n');
  python.stdout.on('data', function(data) {                                                                                                                  
    var output = '' + data;
    s.emit('response', {
      output: output
    }); 
    console.log('python stdout: ' + output);
  }); 
  python.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    var output = '' + data;
    s.emit('response', {
      error: output
    }); 
    console.log('python stderr: ' + output);
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you add an `Event Listener` each time user (client) emits `run` event. 
after ex. 10 `run` events , it will have 10 event listeners that are listening for event of stdout and stderr.

you should move `stdout.on(..)` and `stderr.on(..)` outside the `.on('run',..)`